# How to create named local variable in llvm?

Tags: c++, llvm, named

In a struct like this:

```
struct point{
    int x0;
    int y0;
};
```

How can I pass the names `x0` and `y0` to llvm when I create the `llvm::StructType` with C++ API?

Comment: Look at `AllocaInst` which creates local variable in stack.

Answer (score 1):

You can't; in LLVM IR, fields of structs do not have names.

What you *can* do depends on what you are trying to achieve:

- If you want to enable debug info for these fields, this is not the correct approach anyway - instead, use a `DIBuilder` to [define the struct type](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1DIBuilder.html#ad6079369cab98a0820441dc11d3cd45d).
- If you want to make the IR's textual representation (.ll files and `dump()` results) more readable, you can do something different - whenever a field is accessed, have the frontend use the field name for that field's value. For example:

  ```
  %p.py0 = getelementptr %point* %p, i32 0, i32 1
  %p.y0 = load i32* %p.py0
  ```

  the `getelementptr` that accesses the 2nd field has a name that indicates it's a pointer to a field called `y0`, and the load has a name that indicates it's the actual field. Also notice how the name includes the name of the variable those were accessed from, for extra readability.